# Inserting account using Google Mirror API

Tags: php, google-glass, google-mirror-api

**EDIT**

We have informed google about this and they solved it. Now error dissappeared, but `$service->accounts->insert` now returns just `null` instead of the account.

I am trying to insert an account via Google Mirror API. So what am I doing:

**Client**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($name);
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setDeveloperKey($key);
```

**Service**

```
$service = new Google_Service_Mirror($client);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth'
    ],
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

// THIS IS NOT WORKING
$acc = insert_account($service, $user_token, $user_mail);
```

**Inserting an account**

```
function insert_account($service, $userToken, $email) {

    $accountType = 'do.sli';

    $userDataArray= array();
    $userData1= new Google_Service_Mirror_UserData();
    $userData1->setKey('some');
    $userData1->setValue('data');
    $userDataArray[]=$userData1;

    $authTokenArray= array();
    $authToken1= new Google_Service_Mirror_AuthToken();
    $authToken1->setAuthToken('randomtoken');
    $authToken1->setType('randomType');
    $authTokenArray[]=$authToken1;

    $postBody = new Google_Service_Mirror_Account();
    $postBody->setUserData($userDataArray);
    $postBody->setAuthTokens($authTokenArray);
    $postBody->setFeatures(['access']);

    try {
        $account = $service->accounts->insert($userToken, $accountType, $email, $postBody);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $account;
}
```

**And the var_dump show me this**

`Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/accounts/USER_TOKEN/ACCOUNT/EMAIL?key=DEVELOPERS_KEY: (400) Invalid Value`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong... I have tried many things. Not sure what to check. I am trying to authenticate user from the Glass Store in our web app and insert an account, but this happens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This error usually happens when the `accountType` you are using does not match the one that was entered in the MyGlass backend: make sure you let the review team of the `accountType` that you want to use and double check for typos.

Comment: We have informed google about this and they solved it. Now error dissappeared, but ` $service->accounts->insert` now returns just `null` instead of the account.

Comment: The `null` response body is actually intended: on success, the API will respond with a `201 No Content` response code.

Comment: but documentation says: `If successful, this method returns an Accounts resource in the response body.`. So you basically saying, `null` response is successful inserted account?

Comment: Yes, as stated above, `null` is a success response in this case. Simply check if you have access to the account on your device.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain you don't have access to this API before your app has been accepted to the Glassware "store".

See: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication

Comment: but, i have accepted this app to je store, it is just for our DEVs only, but it is in the store already, so i have the access